# How to set file size in the header in spring boot to display the download progress?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, http-headers, multipart

How to set `file size` in the `header` in spring boot to display the download progress in the client?

```
@GetMapping(value = "/document/{nodeRef}/{versionNumber}")
public byte[] getDocumentWithVersion(@PathVariable(value = "nodeRef") UUID nodeRef, @PathVariable(value = "versionNumber") Double versionNumber) {
    return docService.getDocument(nodeRef, versionNumber);
}
```

Comment: Change the return type to ResponseEntity<byte[]>, then return ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(docBytes.length).body(docBytes);

Comment: Thanks @Daniel F . Just now I fixed. Exact in the same way !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client receives the `header` before the `file` or the `body` starts the download. So added `Content-length` and `content-type` in the `header`.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/document/{nodeRef}/{versionNumber}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDocumentWithVersion(@PathVariable(value = "nodeRef") UUID nodeRef, @PathVariable(value = "versionNumber") Double versionNumber) {
    byte[] file = alfrescoService.getDocument(null, nodeRef, versionNumber);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(file.length));
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(file);
}
```